# How to integrate CARTO map to react.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cartodb

I'm trying to integrate CARTO map (created using CARTO builder) with react.js.

I'm stuck at using carto.js via cartoclient:

```
this.cartoClient = new carto.Client({ apiKey: 'key', username: 'user' });
```

Official CARTO documentation mentions that it's possible to integrate the map using `viz.json` file, but there are no reference to any working example of that.

[This example](https://carto.com/blog/inside/cartojs-and-react/) is creating map from scratch and [this one](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/getting-started/) is using plain html with scripts (no react.js support)

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here is that documentation at https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/ refers to `version 3` while the React example you saw is using `version 4` which documentation is now living here https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/

We are in the process of deprecating `/docs`, sorry for the inconvenience.

Regarding your question the answer is that nowadays we don't have a way to instantiate Builder maps wich CARTO.js. That may change in the future but at this moment we don't support viz.json.

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO

Comment: So the only way is to make the same map in react and carto.js(with carto.Client) is manually using carto builder datasets (if it is possible?)

Comment: Yes, you have to add your layers as combinations of queries (or table names) and CartoCSS definitions.